# Wie nennt man technische Verbesserungen des menschlichen Körpers?

Tags: single-word-request

Eine Prothese, [meint Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prothese), **ersetze** ein fehlendes oder geschädigtes Organ:

> Eine **Prothese** (altgriechisch πρό *pro* „vor, anstatt“ und ϑέσις *thesis* „das Setzen, Stellen“) bezeichnet in der Medizin den Ersatz von Gliedmaßen, Organen oder Organteilen durch künstlich geschaffene, funktionell ähnliche Produkte.

Eine Prothese, so erklärt Wikipedia weiter, kann sich außerhalb des Körpers befinden (wie eine Brille) oder innerhalb (wie ein künstliches Hüftgelenk).

Wie aber nennt man – in einem Oberbegriff – Geräte, die die Funktionen des *gesunden* Körpers erweitern oder **verbessern**? Auf Englisch heißen sie *enhancements*. Beispiele wären die Brillenlupe eines Uhrmachers (Exo...) oder ein Chip, um entführte Kinder zu lokalisieren (Endo.../Implantat).

Comment: Kannst du Beispiele für solche Geräte nennen? Ich kann mir gerade schwer vorstellen, was genau du meinst.

Comment: Es gibt eine "Cyborg-Szene", in der sich Menschen beispielsweise RFC-Chips implantieren, siehe z. B. https://blog.wdr.de/digitalistan/cebit-2016-ich-war-zu-feige-mir-diesen-cyborg-chip-implantieren-zu-lassen/ In der Science Fiction sind solche Techniken seit Jahrzehnten bekannt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Was Henning sagt.

Comment: Zur Ergänzung. **Typen von Prothesen**: Befindet sich die Prothese außerhalb des Körpers wie bei künstlichen Gliedmaßen, spricht man von einer Exoprothese. Beispiele sind Bein-, Arm- oder Handprothesen. Andernfalls handelt es sich um ein Implantat. (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da der Technikdiskurs heute überwiegend englischsprachig geprägt ist, wird sich vermutlich der im Englischen bereits heute gebräuchliche Begriff

## [Enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_enhancement)

durchsetzen. Die Bezeichnung für einen durch Enhancements verbesserten Menschen ist **[Cyborg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg)**.

Comment: Wieso nicht *Erweiterung*?

Comment: Marshall McLuhan fast alle Medien als Erweiterung des Körpers auf, wobei ich die Übersetzung aus der Erinnerung zitiere. Mir ist jetzt nicht klar, ob Du Eindeutschung und Übersetzung synonym verwendest; soweit ich weiß ist Enhancement einfach ein generischer, englischer Begriff, der mit Erweiterung (und einem halben Dutzen anderer Begriffe) treffend übersetzt werden kann, also im engl. Original gerade nicht auf Prothesen u. dgl. beschränkt ist.

Comment: @userunknown Du musst dir immer eine Verwendung vorstellen. Nehmen wir an, in einem Roman unterhalten sich zwei Cyborgs, und der eine sagt: "Meine Erweiterungen funktionieren nicht richtig." Dann denkt der heutige Leser, dass dieser Mensch in seinem Körper technische Geräte eingebaut und diese Geräte dann erweitert hat. Erweiterung bezieht sich im heutigen Sprachgebrauch bereits auf Erweiterungen der Technik, nicht auf Erweiterungen der Biologie durch Technik. Mit diesem Bedeutungswissen versuchen Leser dann Texte zu verstehen, was bei deiner Bedeutungsverwendung zu Missverständnissen führt.

Comment: Wenn Du eine Verwendung in den Raum stellst, bei der sich aus dem Kontext bereits ergibt, dass es sich wohl um ein Enhancement im Sinne von Cyborgtechnologie handelt, dann wäre diese sowohl im englischen wie im Deutschen gegeben und dann könnte auch Erweiterung oder künstliche Verbesserung oder ähnliches im Deutschen ausreichen, um zu verdeutlichen worum es geht. Wenn ein Ami sagt: "I bought an enhencement." wird ohne Kontext kaum jemand auf die Idee kommen, es könnte sich um Cyborgtechnik handeln, auch wenn Du das Wort vielleicht nur aus diesem Kontext kennst.

Comment: @userunknown Wieso schreibst du denn nicht eine Antwort?

Answer (score 2):

Ein künstliches Organ oder Glieder sind naturgemäß [Prothesen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prothese), da sie die vorhandene Funktionen nach einem Verlust ersetzen aber eigentlich nicht verbessern sollen. Man kennt auch noch [Orthesen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthese), die den Körper stützen sollen, auch hier ohne eine Funktionsverbesserung.

Eine tatsächliche Funktionsverbesserung durch in den Körper fest eingebaute oder gar dort verbleibende künstliche Produkte sind auch heute noch weitgehend Science Fiction. Deshalb darf ein geeigneten Wort durchaus auch ein Produkt der Fantasie sein.

Meine Vorschläge für ein neu zu schaffendes Fremdwort aus einer Kombination bekannter altgriechischer Wörter wären:

- **Sophothese** ([*σοφός*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CE%BF%CF%86%CF%8C%CF%82): geschickt, handfertig, intelligent...)
- **Technothese** ([*τέχνη*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CE%AD%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%B7): Kunstfertig, Kunstgiff, Kunst...)

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne keinen gängigen Begriff für diesen (*noch* eher weniger gängigen) Gegenstand.

Was passen könnte, sind

- Aufwertung (im Sinne von "Upgrade" oder "Enhancement"
- [xyz]wertsteigerung (Die Bundeswehr nennt das Upgrade eines Panzers eine *Kampfwertsteigerung*. Möglicherweise findet man darüber einen "amtlichen" Ansatzpunkt)
- Irgendein Neologismus aus *Prothese* und einem Hinweis, dass es sich um eine Erweiterung handelt, z.B. *Exothese*, *Neothese*
- Einen deutsch-basierten Neologismus, wie z.B. *Einbesserung*, *Einsteigerung*

Comment: Erweiterung (Körperfunktionserweiterung,-verbesserung) scheitnt mir sinnvoll.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde eine solche Erweiterung des Körpers als **Add-on** bezeichnen.

> Ein Add-on ergänzt als optionaler Teil ein bestehendes System
>   ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Add-on))

Wer keine eingedeutschte Begriff mag, könnte alternativ: 
*Zusatzmodul*, *Zusatzpaket* oder *Zusatzkomponente* sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Technische Assistenzsysteme, techn. Hilfsmittel, Prothesen, Verbesserungen und Enhancements waren Terme, die in der 3sat-Sendung (SRF) *Vom Menschen zum Cyborg* aus der Reihe *Sternstunde Kultur*, zwischen dem Psychologen Bertold Meyer und dem im EPG nicht genannten Moderator, benutzt wurden, von der der ich allerdings die ersten 20 Minuten verpasst habe.

Im Gegensatz zu *What* bin ich nicht der Ansicht, dass sich Enhancement wohl durchsetzen wird. In der Sprache gibt es einige Beispiele dafür, dass sich englische Fachbegriffe, die anfangs die öffentliche Sprache bestimmten, später im Jedermannsprachgebrauch zurückgezogen haben zugunsten von Übersetzungen. So war es eine zeitlang hip von *Content* zu sprechen, aber heute setzt sich mehr und mehr der *Inhalt* durch.

Dass Prothesen nicht nur ein beschränkter Ersatz sein müssen, sondern auch spezifische Vorteile haben können, könnte dabei ein Aspekt sein, der stärker in den Focus rückt und die kursierenden Definitionen überdenken lässt, wobei man rückblickend feststellen kann, dass dieser schon lange unbeachtet bestanden hat. So schützt eine Brille, die eigentlich nur die Sehkraft verbessern soll, auch vor kleinen Insekten oder Sand, die beim Radfahren ins Auge geraten könnten, ohne dass dies der Anlass war sich eine Brille zuzulegen.

Comment: Sehr gut, vielen Dank. Die genannte Sendung ist übrigens zur Zeit noch in der SRF-Mediathek online und kann mit der Software MediathekView auch heruntergeladen werden. Ich schau sie mir heute Abend mal an und gebe dir dann Feedback. Jedenfalls schon mal eine wirklich hilfreiche Antwort. Danke dir.

Comment: Unter technischen Assistenzsystemen werden einer schnellen Recherche nach eher körperexterne Technologien verstanden, wie Hausnotrufsysteme oder Mobilitätshilfen. Technische Hilfmittel scheinen "Soziale Netzwerke speziell für Senioren" ebenso zu umfassen wie Hörgeräte, der Begriff ist also zu weit. Bleibt die "Verbesserung". Noch hab ich das Video nicht gesehen.

Comment: Die Sendung hat zwei Teile, einen ersten, in dem es um den Sozialpsychologen Meyer, seinen fehlenden Arm und seine Prothese geht. In diesem ersten Teil spricht Meyer von "Assistenztechnologie". Im zweiten Teil dann geht es um die Verbesserung gesunder Menschen durch Gerätetechnik. Diese Verbesserung über den Normalzustand hinaus nennt Meyer *enhancement*. Das Gegenteil von *enhancement* ist für ihn die Therapie, die von einer Behinderung aus den Normalzustand wiederherstellen soll. Einen Begriff für die Geräte, die dem *enhancement* dienen, verwendet er nicht.

Comment: Dass "technische Assistenzsysteme" mehr umfasst, als nur Hilfsmittel die man am oder im Körper ständig mit sich rumführt, wie Hausnotrufsysteme oder unverbundene Krücken ist richtig, trifft aber für *enhancement* ebenso zu.

Answer (score 0):

Meines Wissens hat sich für diese Geräte noch kein einigermaßen verbreiteter Begriff herausgebildet. Meist wird, je nach der verwendeten Technik, allgemein von "Prothese", "Implantat" etc. gesprochen. Die Unterscheidung zu Prothesen im klassischen Sinn wird meist über die (wohlig-schaudrige) Anspielung auf [Cyborg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg) hergestellt, etwa in Schlagzeilen nach dem Motto "Firma XY setzt Cyborg-Implantate ein".

Answer (score 0):

Wenn es durch einen medizinischen Begriff in den Körper eingebaut wird, ist es ein

> **Implantat**

(von lat. *in* »im, hinein« und *planta* »Steckling, Setzling«)

Wenn es dauerhaft an der Außenseite des Körpers angebracht wird habe ich leider keine Ahnung, wie man so etwas nennen könnte. Wenn es nicht dauerhaft mit dem Körper verbunden ist, ist es ganz einfach nur ein Werkzeug. Aber beides war nicht gefragt. (Es wurde ausdrücklich nach Geräten, »die dem gesunden Körper **eingesetzt** werden« gefragt)

Comment: Gefragt war ein Gegenbegriff zur Prothese, der sowohl innere als auch äußere *enhancements* umfasst. Ich habe bewusst nicht "ein- und aufgesetzt" geschrieben, da mir der eine oder andere Schlaumeier dann "Kleidung" vorschlagen würde. Ich habe meine Frage aber nun entsprechend überarbeitet, damit klar wird, dass der gesuchte Begriff mehr umfasst als bloß das Implantat.